# Getting S3::putObject(): [AccessDenied] error for recently created buckets (old ones work fine)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an error that I cannot work out. I am using the following repository to create s3 buckets and upload files to them: https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class.

The buckets I created last August all work fine but those created recently are giving an access denied error despite having exactly the same permissions.

I am programatically creating an s3 bucket which has "Objects can be public" access:

```
$this->s3->putBucket("some name", S3::ACL_PRIVATE, "eu");
```

This creates the bucket without issue.

When I try and upload a file to the bucket as follows:

```
$this->s3->putObjectFile("filename", "some name", "s3 name", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

I get this error returned:

```
S3::putObject(): [AccessDenied] Access Denied
```

But older buckets work fine. I cannot work out where else to look so woud welcome any pointers.

[image]

[updated] to include image of block public access settings

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have S3 Block Public Access enabled? (see https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/block-public-access/)

Comment: @jarmod yes. I have added the permissions page to the original post. The settings here are exactly the same as the other buckets.

Comment: OK, I figured, but just wanted to make 100% sure. At this point, I think you should just carefully review the IAM permissions of your client and the S3 bucket policy. Perhaps the IAM permission are restricted to the older buckets, or the bucket policy has some explicit requirements such as signature v4 or SSE or other.